# Linkedin Sign In Auth fail for some users

Tags: reactjs, api, meteor, linkedin-api

I am getting this error

`{"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"Unable to retrieve access token: appid/redirect uri/code verifier does not match authorization code. Or authorization code expired. Or external member binding exists"}`

when some of my users use the LinkedIn login. It works fine for 70% of the users.

Can someone explain why is this happening..

I'm using running the application on a  NodeJS server.

Comment: Could you find any common factor in the documents of the users whose login fails?

Comment: Check if in the settings of users in LinkedIn, where I guess could be an option to disallow 3rd party api logins with the account.

Comment: having the same issue. Did you find a solution yet?

Comment: Exact same issue here, works for most users, but fails for some. Worst part is because login fails I cannot identify who those users are.